# two-way data binding not working for data-ng-disabled

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How can I can get `btnDisabled` to change the `data-ng-disabled` in the immediate function scope but inside my `ajax` *success* scope nothing is playing nicely. How to I get my button to *disable*?

## JS

```
.controller('CouponCtrl', function($http, $scope) {
  $scope.btnDisabled = false;
  // $scope.btnDisabled = true; // this works fine too

  $http.jsonp("someurl?_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK").success(function(){
    $scope.btnDisabled = true; // does not work
    console.log("I see this so why doesn't my button disable?");

    // $scope.$digest(); // tried this too but I'm told digest is already running
  }
}
```

## HTML

```
<button data-ng-disabled="{{ btnDisabled }}" class="button button-block green">redeem coupon</button>
```

**NOTE**

I've noticed that none of my two-way data binding works when I update a variable via the *ajax success* scope. Is there a way to overcome that?

Comment: Ehh, what is `fetchSomeJsonP` - it's probably not triggering a `$digest` cycle on completion.

Comment: I've manually triggered `$scope.$digest()` at the end of the ajax success function and still nothing, per my comment.

Comment: Alright, where is that HTML located? Is it inside a child controller?

Comment: @tymeJV Yes. I know it works because outside of the ajax success scope I can change the `data-ng-disabled` as desired.

Comment: You have an extra `)` after the `success(function())` (but I think that's a paste typo) - not sure what to say then... try logging the `$scope` inside the callback and outside the call, verify they're the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ngDisabled` [expects](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) an expression, not a string (interpolation always outputs string values):

```
<button data-ng-disabled="btnDisabled" 
        class="button button-block green">redeem coupon</button>
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AocAZmNUeMFPWNc8ScXV?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
data-ng-disabled
```

to

```
ng-disabled
```